# Getting confidence interval for prediction from statsmodel Robust Linear model

Tags: regression, python, linear-model, statsmodels, robust-standard-error

I'm using statsmodels to fit a statistical model. I have a formula that is fitted like this:

```
formula = "Y ~ X1 + X2 + X1:X2"
model =  rlm(formula, data=x_train)
result = model.fit()
```

After I fit the model I want to get, not only the predictions but the confidence interval for the predictions. If I was using the regular `ols` I could do something like this:

```
predictions = result.get_prediction(x_test)
predictions.summary_frame(alpha=0.05)
```

But with the [robust model](https://statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/robust_models_0.html) I get the error below:

```
AttributeError: 'RLMResults' object has no attribute 'get_prediction'
```

How can I get a confidence interval for my prediction with this model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(preliminary answer)

The confidence interval for the predicted mean or conditional expectation `X b` depends on the estimated covariance of the parameters `V(b)`.

The variance of a linear prediction or a linear combination of parameters is `x V(b) x`. This is the same as in the t- or z-test.

So in statsmodels, the confidence interval for the predicted mean can be obtained by

`results.t_test(x_test)`

Prediction interval, i.e. confidence interval for a new observation y, would depend on distributional assumptions and is not directly available in statsmodels.
[Prediction interval for robust regression with MM-estimator](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38075/prediction-interval-for-robust-regression-with-mm-estimator)

as follow-up, I opened
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/8304